# Python - equivalent of Ruby new method

Tags: python, ruby

I'm trying the implement the following into Python:

```rb
NAMES = {"fn" => ["James", "John", "John"], "ln" => ["Smith", "Johnson", "Brown"]}

class RandomNameGenerator
  def self.generate
    new.to_s
  end

  def initialize
    @fn = NAMES['fn'].sample
    @ls = NAMES['ln'].sample
  end

  def to_s
    @fn + " " + @ls
  end
end
```

Which returns:

```
>> RandomNameGenerator.generate
=> "James Smith"
>> RandomNameGenerator.generate
=> "John Johnson"
```

My code thus far looks like:

```py
import random

NAMES = {"fn": ["James", "John", "John"], "ln": ["Smith", "Johnson", "Brown"]}

class RandomNameGenerator(object):
    @classmethod
    def generate(cls):
        RandomNameGenerator().__str__

    def __init__(self):
        self.fn = random.choice(NAMES["fn"])
        self.ln = random.choice(NAMES["ln"])

    def __str__(self):
       return self.fn + " " + self.ln
```

```py
>>> RandomNameGenerator.generate()
>>> print(RandomNameGenerator.generate())
None
```

I feel like Ruby's `new.to_s` isn't the same as Python's`RandomNameGenerator().__str__`. What am I not understanding?

Comment: You're not *calling* the method, or returning anything. Why not `return str(cls())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't return anything in the generate method. Also the `__init__` code is called when you initialiaze the class, in you case you are not doing it. You are just calling the class static method. In order to make your code work you have to create a new instance of the RandomNameGenerator in the generate method.

```
class RandomNameGenerator(object):
    @classmethod
    def generate(cls):
        return cls()

    def __init__(self):
        self.fn = random.choice(NAMES["fn"])
        self.ln = random.choice(NAMES["ln"])

    def __str__(self):
       return self.fn + " " + self.ln
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning from the method `generate()`:

```
import random

NAMES = {"fn": ["James", "John", "John"], "ln": ["Smith", "Johnson", "Brown"]}

class RandomNameGenerator(object):
    @classmethod
    def generate(cls):
        return str(cls())

    def __init__(self):
        self.fn = random.choice(NAMES["fn"])
        self.ln = random.choice(NAMES["ln"])

    def __str__(self):
       return self.fn + " " + self.ln

for i in range(5):
    print(RandomNameGenerator.generate())
```

OUTPUT:

```
John Johnson
John Brown
James Johnson
James Brown
James Johnson
```